# Review sections to be always in the same place

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

I find it not comfortable to have the order of the review sections changing all the time.

Within few seconds it changed from

> [image]

to

> [image]

Wouldn't it be better to have all of them in the same position, no matter the number of posts in each queue?

It assumes that the most important part is to lower the queue, although it is said there is no problem in having Close Votes with thousands of items. IMOH, most of us prefer going to one or other section (for example I like "Suggested edits") rather than to the queue with the most items, so having them changing their position makes it not that intuitive.

What do you think?

Comment: I can see the sorting make sense if there were dozens of queues, to see where the work was more easily. But with only 6 of these rows, it just seems like weird UX.

Comment: I personally really dislike this suggestion. I like being able to keep my mouse hovered over the top queue, and when a review task comes in, being able to just click the queue.

Comment: Well in fact what I pretend is to open the debate, so I think it is better to reply with arguments rather than downvoting.

Comment: Well I think I will not have the option to award the bounty : (

Answer (score 1):

**Simplest Answer :**

They are trying to provide **"Human Readability"** to read the Questions or Answers from the Section (like Close Votes , Re-open Votes) with more Traffic of Questions or Answers.So more chance to reduce the load from Each Section. So, they Sort the Sections according to the Traffic in Each Section.
[image]

Comment: +1 for the picture and explanation :) Anyway, what I pretend with my question is to propose changing the way it is sorted and have each thing in the same place. Following your words, the Traffic is not that huge and so many threads to make it necessary to sort them. Let's say I think it is not very intuitive.